# Repeater Skipping First Row on ItemDataBound

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a repeater with 9 items where the values are assigned on the client side page and all 9 show complete.

I am editing the item images on the server side with ItemDataBound, but it only returns 8 of the 9. I debugged it and it never picks up the first item. Any ideas?

ASPX:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rep_FeaturedProds" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" OnItemDataBound="rep_FeaturedProds_OnItemDataBound">
      <ItemTemplate>
          <li>
               <div class="Homepage_FeaturedProds_HR"></div>
                   <div class="Homepage_FeaturedProds_HR_Item">
                       <a href='Product.aspx?pid=<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"decID") %>'>
                           <div id="Homepage_FeaturedProds_BG" class="Homepage_FeaturedProds_BG" runat="server">
                                    <div class="Homepage_FeaturedProds_Thumb"><img id="imgProduct_Thumb" runat="server" /></div>
                           </div>
                           <div class="Homepage_FeaturedProds_Title"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"productDefaultName") %></div>
                           <div class="Homepage_FeaturedProds_Rating"></div>
                           <div class="Homepage_FeaturedProds_MoreInfo">More Info ></div>
                           <asp:HiddenField ID="hfDecId" runat="server" Value='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"decID") %>' />
                        </a>
                  </div>
             </li>
     </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

C# Code:

```
protected void rep_FeaturedProds_OnItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        foreach (RepeaterItem ri in rep_FeaturedProds.Items)
        {
            HtmlImage imgProduct_Thumb = (HtmlImage)e.Item.FindControl("imgProduct_Thumb");
            HiddenField hfImageFileName = (HiddenField)e.Item.FindControl("hfDecId");
            HtmlGenericControl Homepage_FeaturedProds_BG = (HtmlGenericControl)e.Item.FindControl("Homepage_FeaturedProds_BG");

            string imgPath = "~/Uploads/Images/ProductThumbs/";
            string decId = hfImageFileName.Value + "_thumb.png";

            if (System.IO.File.Exists(Server.MapPath(imgPath + decId)))
            {
                imgProduct_Thumb.Src = imgPath + decId;
            }
            else
            {
                imgProduct_Thumb.Src = imgPath + "0000_thumb.png";

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried debugging your code to see if there is any problem in your event code?

Comment: your `foreach` loop isn't accomplishing anything, you can take that line out.

Comment: @lincolnk - That was the issue. I used that for the FindControl as ri.findcontrol and changed it to e.item. It was like that either way.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AS @Lincolnk mentioned, removing the following line fixed the issue. Even when reference the control to find with ri.findcontrol, this issue was present. Fixed by removing and using e.Item.FindControl.

```
foreach (RepeaterItem ri in rep_FeaturedProds.Items)
```

Comment: Switching .Items to .Controls fixes this issue. No need to remove foreach.